# what is the solution for links and forms when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 questions about Rails and javascript when it's disabled

**1)** first case is `link_to` method which doesn't work and it get the *show page* if it's normally supposed to go to destroy action, the solution for that is what we know as "graceful degradation",  but what i want is to prevent the link from working if js is disabled. what is the way to do that ?

**2)** the second question is about logout functionality (wich use destroy action), so i have a **link** for logging out :

```
link_to "logout", logout_path, method: "delete"
```

in my routes file i have the following line :

```
match "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy", via: 'delete'
```

if i disable javascript i get the error :

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

is it safe to add also via: 'get' ?? to this route like this :

```
match "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy", via: ['delete', 'get']
```

**3)** last question is when i have a form with submit button, if javascript is disable i get the error :

```
 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in RelationshipsController#destroy
```

which means in production i get the page "something went wrong..." what is the solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use link_to / button_to "method: delete" it will generate something like this.

```
<form action="/something" class="button_to" method="post">
    <div>
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value="Delete"> 
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="gP+sFWt9Y3r0m8U4gqqoax+tnKwIIalHVxhkC2IyoHY=">
    </div>
</form>
```

jquery-ujs hijacks the click, when it sees the _method is delete. It doesn't use GET/POST, it uses DELETE.

(In regards to #3: notice the authenticity_token generated from the link_to / button_to. I don't know enough to speak on it in detail)

TL:DR; It's not very common for developers to use a DELETE call to "logout" a user. Just use GET and make your life easier.